# JavaScript div onclick function not executing

Tags: javascript, onclick

On the square game, 2 player (1 player does not work yet), when a player wins, a div pops up and congratulates them. The div has an onclick function to close the div, but the onclick function doesn't appear to be executing and the div does not close.

```
  win.setAttribute('onclick', 'close()');
}

function on_win(winner) {
  document.getElementById('win').style.display = 'inline-block';
  document.getElementById('win_center').appendChild(winner);
}

function close() {
  console.log("close");
  document.getElementById('win').style.display = 'none';
}
```

[See it in action here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/harleycalvert/scgame/blob/scgame/index.html)

Comment: Instead of this: `win.setAttribute('onclick', 'close()')` do `win.addEventListener('click', close)`

Comment: thanks, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 win.onclick = close;
```